# Not including space in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string where I want CL3 and everything the proceeds it.

String:

```
"1600m Dead CL3  $4,500"
```

What I want:

```
CL3  $4,500
```

This is my current regex:

```
[^(Dead|Good|Heavy|Slow|Fast)]+$
```

At the moment Python returns an empty string and in an online regex engine: http://regex101.com/r/jU4zO5/1 returns the space after the Dead.

Your assistance is much appreciated!

**EDIT**

I want everything after the the possibilities of (Dead|Good|Heavy|Slow|Fast) and this means it won't necessarily be starting with CL3.

eg. 
String: "3200m Good Melbourne Cup $4,500"

Desired: Melbourne Cup $4,500

Comment: What do you think square brackets do in regexp? I don't understand why you have them around the parentheses.

Comment: Read the explanation of your regex on regex101. All characters inside square brackets are interpreted literal. So you are matching everything which is not `(Dead|GoHvySlwFst)`.

Comment: Why not simply do `CL3.*`

Comment: Actually `CL3.*` would be enough I guess.

Comment: I suppose you want all words, filtering out the specified ones. But why don't you expect `1600m` also? Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
txt='''
1600m Dead CL3  $4,500
3200m Good Melbourne Cup $4,500'''

import re

>>> re.findall(r'^.*(?:Dead|Good|Heavy|Slow|Fast)\s+(.*)', txt, re.M)
['CL3  $4,500', 'Melbourne Cup $4,500']
```

Answer (score 2):

With this regular expression, just grab the second capture group.

```
(Dead|Good|Heavy|Slow|Fast)(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:Dead|Good|Heavy|Slow|Fast)(.*)
```